# What is better -to call empty methods or to use many interfaces

Tags: c#

I'm having a few classes that have one base class named Tool. 
In form i have one Tool reference that contains one of the instaces of mentioned classes.
When a MouseDown event occurs on the form i call the current Tool Method ex. "CurrentTool.MethodWhenMouseDown()".

Most of Tools are having 3 methods:

```
MethodWhenMouseDown()
MethodWhenMouseUp()
MethodWhenMouseMove()
```

But one or two classes are having just:

```
MethodWhenMouseDown()
```

Now which is better:

1.To have all three methods in Tool and the the classes that don't need them just call empty methods.

2.To implement interfaces ex. IMouseMoveListener that would be implemented just by the classes that need to act when MouseMove event occurs. This way if MouseMove event occurs we would ask:

```
if(CurrentTool is MouseMoveListener)
{
(CurrentTool as IMouseMoveListener).MethodWhenMouseMove();
}
```

Additional information:
The program is like Ms Paint - the tools are Brush,Bucket(the one that don't need MethodWhenMouseMove),LineTool etc.
In my PaintForm i have one reference of abstrac base class Tool that stores instace one of derived class. The thing that fires event is pictureBox.

> Have you considered events to which the tools subscribes? – CodesInChaos

I thougth it would be good practice to have a method in form, that would be called after an evet occurs and the method is calling the siutable method of CurrentTool. ex:

```
void MouseMoveSubscriber(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
CurrentTool.MethodWhenMouseMove(e);
}
```

I assume subscribing and unsubscribing the method of CurrentTool each time the CurrentTool was changed a bad practice?
 I also thought about having all tool refereces in Form and the event would be subscribed by each tool and there would be no need of unsubscrinig. The big drawback in my opinion is that each tool needs to check if it is the CurrentTool.
What you think about it? Thanks for help given.

Comment: Have you considered events to which the tools subscribes?

Comment: It is unclear why a Tool can't just subscribe the event it wants to listen too.

Answer (score 2):

Performance is not an issue (when the user clicks, the overhead of calling an empty function unnecessarily is of no significance), so this is really about coding ease and code clarity/complexity/maintainability.

So I'd keep it as simple as possible.

I would implement a base class with empty implementations, as this is clean and simple. It requires minimal code in a derived class to get the results you need. It also makes sense (If you don't override the click upcall, you are essentially saying "when a mouse is clicked I wish to do nothing about it").

The next option would be to provide events for mouse up/down/click, and have derived classes subscribe to the events if they wish to. Using events is a standard pattern, but it has the drawback that you have to mess around with the ugly subscription and unsubscription calls. The benefit of this is that if you make them public, these events can be handled by anybody, not just derived classes.

I'd avoid using interfaces and casting - to me this feels like a clunky approach - all it really achieves is fragmenting the "empty functions" approach across a number of different types instead of a simple set of 3 virtual methods. And instead of just calling the methods and knowing they will work, you have to do a lot of type casting and checks first - it just seems messy.

**edit**
Since you've added some more to the question, I've re-read it and another possibility springs to mind: Create a base Tool class that provides the virtual MouseDown handler that *all* derived classes need to override. All the normal tools would derive form this.

An additional DragTool class could the derived as an intermediate class that adds the MouseMove and MouseUp handlers that are needed for your special couple of dragging tools.

i.e.

```
ToolBase (abstract MouseDown)
  |
  +- ClickTool1
  +- ClickTool2
  +- DragToolBase (abstract MouseMove + MouseUp)
      |
      +- DragTool1
      +- DragTool2
```

This would meant there would be no empty implementations in any of your tools.

Comment: I disagree with "clunky approach". The interfaces he mentioned are so called "Role Interfaces" and that's the way to use them, if a consumer supports multiple roles.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Interfaces are a good approach where a set of unrelated classes need to support a common behaviour, but inventing an entire new interface just to avoid using a virtual method in a handful of directly related classes is overkill IMHO. (It appears for this question that it would mean more code, more complexity, harder to understand, and less efficient. In what way is it a win? It just doesn't seem to be an approriate pattern to apply to this particular case. Unless there is more to this case than the question implies)

Comment: I agree: If the ONLY place these interfaces are used is this one form, the interfaces are overkill. I assumed that there are other places where an `IMouseMoveListener` would be needed without the need of an `IMouseDownListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your scenario, I would go with a combination of interfaces and base class:
The base class implements all interfaces with empty virtual methods. The base class is a pure convenience construct. If a tool class wants to inherit from the base class but doesn't need the method it doesn't override it.

In the code that consumes the tools you would work soley with the interfaces. Like this other classes are free to directly implement your interfaces. You gain maximum flexibility like this without any sacrifices.

```
var mouseMoveListener = CurrentTool as IMouseMoveListener;
var mouseDownListener = CurrentTool as IMouseDownListener;
// ...

if(mouseMoveListener != null)
    mouseMoveListener.MethodWhenMouseMove();
if(mouseDownListener != null)
    mouseDownListener.MethodWhenMouseDown();
```

Please note: I used `as` only instead of `is` in combination with `as`.

Comment: I'm afraid i did'n understend the second paragraph. If a base class implements all this interfaces all the derived classes implements them also so i don't see the chance the CurrentTool not to be the IMouseMoveListener or IMouseDownListener.

Comment: @user1593872: That observation is correct. But other classes could decide to only implement one of the interfaces without deriving from "`ToolBase`".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on actual case. But in your specific case (UI events) I think that have base class with empty handlers (virtual methods) is better than a lot of interfaces. Actually all your tools will inherit from some ToolBase. And invocation code will be smaller and simplier without casting to interfaces.